# How do i find li element in the UL class tag using beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How do I find a `<li>` element in the `<ul>` class tag using beautifulsoup?

```html
<div class="listing-container">
<ul class="listing-items">
  <li>
      <article class="listing-item listing-tenants">
      <a href="https://www.capitaland.com/sg/malls/rafflescity/en/stores/chewy-junior.html" target="_self"> 
  </li>
```

My ideal output would be a link in the `href` attribute of the `<a>` tag:           https://www.capitaland.com/sg/malls/rafflescity/en/stores/chewy-junior.html

Comment: It is dynamically pulled from `https://www.capitaland.com/apis/........r/1/16.json` You can find the full url in the network tab of your browser for the API to call. Start link for others is: `https://www.capitaland.com/sg/malls/rafflescity/en/stores.html?category=foodandbeverage`

Comment: I can't find all URL of all merchants in the page though, is there any way i can pull all merchant links in the page ?

Comment: Meaning the page will only load 16 merchants at one go, so i have to repeat numerous times in order to get all merchant links?

Comment: Possibly. Check the API call for a limit param. Or if the page requires you to load more/has pagination then select for me and monitor the network tab for another API call. By page do you mean that API call?

Answer (score 0):

The page is within the url parameters. Just iterate through that once you know how many pages you need to go through:

```
import requests
import math

page = 1
api_url = 'https://www.capitaland.com/apis/sg/en/properties/rafflescitysingaporeshoppingcentre/cl%3Aentity/tenants/cl%3Arelated-page/%2Fcontent%2Fcapitaland%2Fsg%2Fmalls%2Frafflescity%2Fen%2Fstores/cl%3Asortby/jcr%3Atitle/asc/cl%3Aselectors/_rel_brandtenants_details/_rel_deals/_rel_properties_details/_rel_tenants_details/accepts/acceptsCapita3Eats/acceptsCapitacard/acceptsCapitavoucher/acceptschope/acceptseCapitavoucher/addressroadname/assettype/brand/capita3EatsLink/chopelink/city/country/countryCode/cq%3Atags/currency/dealExisted/enddate/endtime/entityType/entityname/firstPublished/jcr%3Atitle/listingTypePages/logoImgPath/malllocationnote/marketingcategory/nearesttrainstation/oldprice/pagePath/pageTitle/price/promotiontype/ribbon/ribboncolor/shortdescription/startdate/starttime/state/subtitle/thumbnail/tileColorScheme/tilesubtext/cl%3Apgcursor/{page}/16.json'.format(page=page)
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.190 Safari/537.36'}

jsonData = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers, verify = False).json()

total_pages = math.ceil(jsonData['totalcount'] / 16)

links = []
for page in range(1,total_pages+1):
    print('Page: %s of %s' %(page,total_pages))
    if page == 1: 
        pass
    else:
        api_url = 'https://www.capitaland.com/apis/sg/en/properties/rafflescitysingaporeshoppingcentre/cl%3Aentity/tenants/cl%3Arelated-page/%2Fcontent%2Fcapitaland%2Fsg%2Fmalls%2Frafflescity%2Fen%2Fstores/cl%3Asortby/jcr%3Atitle/asc/cl%3Aselectors/_rel_brandtenants_details/_rel_deals/_rel_properties_details/_rel_tenants_details/accepts/acceptsCapita3Eats/acceptsCapitacard/acceptsCapitavoucher/acceptschope/acceptseCapitavoucher/addressroadname/assettype/brand/capita3EatsLink/chopelink/city/country/countryCode/cq%3Atags/currency/dealExisted/enddate/endtime/entityType/entityname/firstPublished/jcr%3Atitle/listingTypePages/logoImgPath/malllocationnote/marketingcategory/nearesttrainstation/oldprice/pagePath/pageTitle/price/promotiontype/ribbon/ribboncolor/shortdescription/startdate/starttime/state/subtitle/thumbnail/tileColorScheme/tilesubtext/cl%3Apgcursor/{page}/16.json'.format(page=page)
        jsonData = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers, verify = False).json()
               
    properties = jsonData['properties']
    for each in properties:
        pagePath = each['pagePath']
        links.append(pagePath)

print(links)
```

**Output:**

240 links

```
['https://www.capitaland.com/sg/malls/rafflescity/en/stores/chewy-junior', 'https://www.capitaland.com/sg/malls/rafflescity/en/stores/a-one-signature', 'https://www.capitaland.com/sg/malls/rafflescity/en/stores/aesop', 'https://www.capitaland.com/sg/malls/rafflescity/en/stores/aldo',... 'https://www.capitaland.com/sg/malls/rafflescity/en/stores/xing-ji-big-prawn-noodle-opening-soon', 'https://www.capitaland.com/sg/malls/rafflescity/en/stores/xw-western-grill', 'https://www.capitaland.com/sg/malls/rafflescity/en/stores/ya-kun-kaya-toast', 'https://www.capitaland.com/sg/malls/rafflescity/en/stores/ysl-beauty', 'https://www.capitaland.com/sg/malls/rafflescity/en/stores/_house_yamamoto']
```